# TypeScript type checks stored as a variable then used in if statement

Tags: typescript

I've got some type checks happening in `if` statements but when I move them to variables Typescript complains. I have done this in other repos before so I'm wondering, is there a `ts` setting I can enable to get it to accept type checks within variables (and not explicitly within the `if(...)` piece of code?

Here's code the works as expected (with no errors because of the type check:

```
if (clickedReport.__typename === LookerItemTypes.AvailableReport) {
    clickedReport.lookerUrl = await getReportUrl(clickedReport);
}
```

And here's some that gives me an error:

```
const matchesType = clickedReport.__typename === LookerItemTypes.AvailableReport;
if (matchesType) {
    clickedReport.lookerUrl = await getReportUrl(clickedReport);
}
```

Here are the errors showing (because `lookerUrl` is supposedly undefined)

[image: code with errors]

I wondered if it was because of an out of date TypeScript version (I'm on `"typescript": "4.0.2"`) but then I tried doing something similar in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and it gave me the same issue.

Comment: can you share your similar [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to work in typescript 4.4.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#cfa-aliased-conditions

You can check it in playground. This example checks in beta, but doesn't in current stable version.

[4.4.0-beta example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZygXigbyqSAuKAIgEFCAaKAQwLgFcBbAIwgCcoBfKAHyx3AgKEAQuSiMaDZm3YAoOQBMIAYwA2lFtCUoAzsCi1EKAvGRwA3HK1xdUBNuLp9huADpc0NJ6KkLMhADMoAAo7YgBKLBkoaKgrbSQVCBcVJABzIINTF0owi04IFW1oTCiYuISklPTMlBdGXJlZGSA)

[4.3.5 example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZygXigbyqSAuKAIgEFCAaKAQwLgFcBbAIwgCcoBfKAHyx3AgKEAQuSiMaDZm3YAoOQBMIAYwA2lFtCUoAzsCi1EKAvGRwA3HK1xdUBNuLp9huADpc0NJ6KkLMhADMoAAo7YgBKLBkoaKgrbSQVCBcVJABzIINTF0owi04IFW1oTCiYuISklPTMlBdGXJlZGSA)